# Is there an "Update if not exists insert" (like replace in MySQL)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is there an "update if not exists insert" function in **Redshift**, like `replace` in MySQL?

If not, what should I do instead?

Comment: Look for `upsert' on SO, you'll find lotof answers

Answer (score -2):

there is a other way

INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a)+VALUES(b);

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/insert-on-duplicate-key-update/

you right, sorry

Comment: I'm not sure it can works on Redshift